# C - Increase Integer In Loop

Tags: c, integer

I'm trying to increase `0.001f` in a loop, so in loop 1 the value is `0.001f`, in loop 2 the value is `0.002f`

This is what I have (doesn't work since it doesn't include the `i` in the value and it's not correct):

```
for (int i = 0; i < 34; i++) {
    GRAPHICS::DRAW_RECT(0.825f, ((maxOptions * 0.000f++) + 0.1765f), 0.23f, 0.035f, scrollerColor.r, scrollerColor.g, scrollerColor.b, scrollerColor.a); // Scroller
}
```

I have tried making a buffer like so, but as expected that didn't work:

```
int buffer[10];
sprintf(buffer, "0.00%if", i);
```

How would I do this? ANswers are appreciated!

Comment: Think about what the numeric relationship between 34 and 0.034 is.

Comment: `sprintf` expects a `char*`, you are passing a `int*`, of course it's not going to work

Comment: The code is not C. Please don't tag unrelated languages

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The variable i is never used inside your loop. Maybe you could tell us where you want to use it, or add more context to the question?

But here's my first raw attempt at an answer anyway:

```
for (float i = 0; i < 0.034f; i += 0.001f) {
    GRAPHICS::DRAW_RECT(0.825f, ((maxOptions * 0.000f++ /* This part has an issue and I can't understand what you mean by it*/) + 0.1765f), 0.23f, 0.035f, scrollerColor.r, scrollerColor.g, scrollerColor.b, scrollerColor.a); // Scroller
}
```

Due to the way your processor handles floating point arithmetic, this code can result in one more or less loop as pointed out by dbush (thanks!)

You can fix it as follows:

```
// Include math.h at the top of your code.
for (float i = 0; fabs(i - 0.034f) > 0.0001; i += 0.001f) {
    GRAPHICS::DRAW_RECT(0.825f, ((maxOptions * 0.000f++ /* This part has an issue and I can't understand what you mean by it*/) + 0.1765f), 0.23f, 0.035f, scrollerColor.r, scrollerColor.g, scrollerColor.b, scrollerColor.a); // Scroller
}
```

Comment: @J.Doe Note that this approach can potentially result in one more or one less iteration that you expect due to the inexact nature of floating point math.  Better to use integers as a loop control variable.

Comment: yeh, the floating point can truncate and give you 0.000999999999 instead of 0.001 at some point, therefore, always check for a difference in the absolute value less than a threshold when comparing floats for equality.

Comment: Fixed the answer. I believe fabs(i - 0.034f) should always be greater than 0.0001 unless they're equal, in which case the comparison will truncate the error. Haven't tested it, so this is just code-in-theory!

Answer (score 1):

`0.000f++` is invalid syntax, as the postincrement operator cannot be used on constants.  It can only be used on an lvalue (i.e. the name of a variable or an expression that represents one).

Assuming you want this value to range from 0.001 to 0.034 you would multiply 0.001 by the loop index, changing the loop to go from 1 to 34 instead of 0 to 33.

```
for (int i = 1; i <= 34; i++) {
    GRAPHICS::DRAW_RECT(0.825f, ((maxOptions * 0.001f * i) + 0.1765f),
                        0.23f, 0.035f, scrollerColor.r, scrollerColor.g,
                        scrollerColor.b, scrollerColor.a); // Scroller
}
```